# Collapsing toolbar layout with NestedScrollView doesnt scroll smoothly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `NestedScrollView` with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and I would like to make it work smoothly.

My problem is when scrolling up from content, my Collapsing Toolbar doesn't auto expand but is blocked when it hits top. Then i need to scroll up again in order to expand toolbar.

I would like to achieve smooth scrolling up from content that would auto expand my `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/product_detail_main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:apptools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom|right"
            android:foregroundTintMode="add"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       /*
           CONTENT
       */

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I found some similar questions but none of the answers worked for me.

Comment: Try to set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: found any solution on this?

Answer (score 3):

**What kind of content is inside LinearLayout ?**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   /*
       CONTENT
   */

</LinearLayout>
```

**If** one of the content is recyclerview, the reason why collapsing toolbar does not respond to scrolling is because `NestedScrollView` does not call `AppBarLayout.Behavour` class when it receive scroll events from recyclerview. that is, when a scroll happens in recyclerview, recyclerview  dispatches/passes the scroll progress to `NestedScrollView`. `NestedScrollView` receives the scroll event but does nothing with it.

**Inside nestedscrollview class**

```
@overide
public void onNestedpreScroll(View target,int dx, int dy, int[] consumed){
         //Do nothing
}
```

To overcome this and make appbarlayout expand/collapse when scrolling recyclerview, just create a custom class that extends NestedScrollView and overide the above method and call method `dispatchNestedPreScroll()` which informs the appbarlayout of the scroll event and make it respond to it.

```
  public class CustomNestedScrollView extends NestedScrollView{

    public CustomNestedScrollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    }

    public CustomNestedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomNestedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

  @overide
  public void onNestedPreScroll(View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed){
    dispatchNestedPreScroll(dx,dy,consumed,null);
  }
}
```

And then use this class in your layout.xml

```
<com.my.package.CustomNestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   /*
       CONTENT
   */

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @MitulVarmora you can provide us with your layout in order to know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that problem by SmoothAppBarLayout
Link: https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout

Add this dependency in your app level build.gradle

```
compile "me.henrytao:smooth-app-bar-layout:25.3.1.0"
```

Mark that child of NestedScrollView should have clickable and focusable true.
This is XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable .../>
</data>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayoutPlaceDetail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adViewPlaceDetail"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <me.henrytao.smoothappbarlayout.SmoothAppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
                <!--app:layout_scrollInterpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"-->

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgOfPlace"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </me.henrytao.smoothappbarlayout.SmoothAppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutInNestedScroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                <YOUR CONTENT VIEWS>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adViewPlaceDetail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="..."
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code after `RecyclerView` adapter is set in `.java` class:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(View-name, false);
```

Comment: you should explain more  and format your code, thanks